# Changes made within a function is still present even after exiting that function. How to handle out of scope values in python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, scope, python-3.8

I'm writing a python code where I'm copying a list variable into another variable and then passing original variable to a function as an argument. But when I print both the list variables at the end, both are getting modified and this is not what I want. One such example is,

```
def fun(list_1):
    list_1.append(4)

list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = list_1
fun(list_1)

print(list_1)  #prints [1,2,3,4] as output
print(list_2)  #also prints [1,2,3,4] as output
```

Since `list_2` is not passed to the function, I don't know how and why it's value is changing. I was expecting `list_1 = [1,2,3,4]` and `list_2 = [1,2,3]`. Please let me know how do I solve this issue (I'm using python 3.8 ).

Answer (score 0):

Here, by using `=` operator, list_1's reference is getting stored in list_2. So changes made in any one list will always reflect in other list as well. To avoid this problem, one should use copy.copy() method. The solution for above problem is,

instead of `list_2 = list_1`, `list_2 = copy.copy(list_1)` or `list_2 = copy.deepcopy(list_1)` can be used. 2nd option is incase list has any nested lists.

The modified code can be,

```
import copy

def fun(list_1):
    list_1.append(4)

list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = copy.copy(list_1)
fun(list_1)

print(list_1)  #prints [1,2,3,4] as output
print(list_2)  #prints [1,2,3] as output
```

Comment: Another way is to replace the statement to  `list_2 = list_1[:]`  to create a new copy.